# c- Karp-Rabin rolling hash - skip and append parts

Tags: c, algorithm, rabin-karp

I need a little help with a particular part of my Karp-Rabin algo.
What I am trying to do is to implement both the version with fixed `sliding window` and with separate `append` and `skip` parts. `Sliding window` works perfectly fine. The problem occurs when I try to split the monolith `sliding window` into `append` and `skip` parts. `Append` seems to work fine, but `skip` is the thing that have been causing me a massive headache last couple of days.

**PROBLEM** - I am sliding through the string that holds a few instances of a pattern subscribing in it. `Sliding window` detects it, but not the other two.

The idea is that the `RH` struct holds the pre-computed value of *(base ^ window size) mod prime number* (`b2wmod`) so I can delete the leading character of a string. This value changes after all `append` and `skip` as window size changes. To decrease the value of `b2wmod`, the multiplicative inverse is used to not be in a situation of mod deletion (inverse of *base mod modulus value*) . It is also pre-computed.

Below are the parts of the code I am interested in. I don't post the whole code to not make you read everything, but can upload it if necessary. Multiplicative inverse seems to be computed correctly, but I can upload the code also.

Would appreciate any help! Thank you in advance!

```
void
append_to_rh(RH rh)
{
    uint64_t hash    = rh->hash;
    uint64_t base    = rh->base;
    uint64_t mod     = rh->mod;
    uint64_t b2wmodm = rh->b2wmodm;
    char     new     = rh->new;
    
    hash             = ( hash * base + new ) % mod;    
    b2wmodm          = ( b2wmodm * base ) % mod;
    
    rh->hash         = hash;
    rh->b2wmodm      = b2wmodm;
}

void
skip(RH rh)
{
    uint64_t hash       = rh->hash;
    uint64_t base       = rh->base;
    uint64_t mod        = rh->mod;
    uint64_t b2wmodm    = rh->b2wmodm;
    uint64_t m_inv      = rh->m_inv;
    char     old        = rh->old;
    uint64_t correction = old * mod;
   
    b2wmodm = ( b2wmodm * (m_inv % mod) ) % mod;
    hash    = ( hash - old * b2wmodm + correction ) % mod;

    rh->hash    = hash;
    rh->b2wmodm = b2wmodm;
}

void
slide_window(RH rh)
{
    uint64_t base    = rh->base;
    uint64_t mod     = rh->mod;
    uint64_t hash    = rh->hash;
    uint64_t b2wmodm = rh->b2wmodm;
    char old = rh->old;
    char new = rh->new;

    hash     = ( hash * base - old * b2wmodm + new ) % mod;
    rh->hash = hash;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `append` and `skip` functions work fine. Here is a sample code I used for testing

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

typedef long long ll;

ll hash, b2wmodm, base, inv_base, mod;

// fast exponentiation, for calculating inv_base
ll exp(ll a, ll b){
    ll ans = 1;
    while (b){
        if (b&1){
            ans *= a;
            ans %= mod;
        }
        a *= a;
        a %= mod;
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return ans;
}

// calculates expected hash of the string
ll expected_hash(std::string s) {
    ll result = 0;
    ll multiplier = 1;
    for (int i = s.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result += s[i] * multiplier % mod;
        result %= mod;
        multiplier = multiplier * base % mod;
    }
    return result;
}

// same as your append and skip functions
void append_to_rh(ll newc) {
    hash = (hash * base + newc) % mod;
    b2wmodm = (b2wmodm * base) % mod;
}

void skip(ll old) {
    ll correction = old * mod;

    b2wmodm = (b2wmodm * (inv_base % mod)) % mod;
    hash = (hash - old * b2wmodm + correction) % mod;
}

int main() {

    base = 29;
    mod = 1000000007;

    hash = 0;
    b2wmodm = 1;
    inv_base = exp(base, mod-2);

    srand(time(nullptr));
    std::string s;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        if (i < 1000 || rand()%2) {
            char newchar = rand()%26 + 'a';
            s += newchar;
            append_to_rh(newchar);
            assert(expected_hash(s) == hash);
        } else {
            char oldchar = s[0];
            s = s.substr(1, s.length());
            skip(oldchar);
            assert(expected_hash(s) == hash);
        }
    }
}
```

I guess other parts of your code cause problems. Maybe you are trying to skip an empty window, or maybe you use a non-prime mod.

Comment: Dear Sir, accept my deepest gratitude! That was indeed a problem in my prime number i thought i checked for million times. That problem made me really desperate, so i literally owe you a little favor now for checking this question)